# CentOS 6.6 - Another df vs du issue

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, disk-usage

I know this has been discussed many times, but I couldn't find my solution anywhere. I have a CentOS 6.6 system that has the root filesystem with 28GB used when I use `df` command. However, `du` shows me 18GB. Yeah, I know they are different, but 10GB difference? That seems too much. I already tried to find deleted files that would be still opened using `lsof`, but there are none. I also already rebooted the server, and after the reboot, this 10GB difference is still there.

```
[root@5377 ~]# df -h  
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sda3             34G   28G  4.5G  86% /  
tmpfs                 63G   28K   63G   1% /dev/shm  
/dev/sda1            477M   33M  420M   8% /boot  
/dev/sda4             29G  1.1G   27G   4% /radcom  
/dev/sda5             24G  384M   23G   2% /var  
/dev/mapper/vg-data   38T  820G   35T   3% /data  


[root@5377 /]# du -a / --exclude=data | sort -n -r | head -n 10  
18570395        /  
8388612 /mnt  
8388608 /mnt/huge  
4656460 /usr  
1906848 /usr/share  
1703512 /home  
1287484 /extra-pkgs  
1156744 /home/nfsroot  
1156740 /home/nfsroot/telefonica_10_8_05_4  
1106840 /usr/lib64
```

The `exclude=data` argument is because it's a filesystem that contains a lot of files and it causes the du command to take a long time. Since we have a dedicate partition for it, that's not the root cause.

Is there anything else that could cause that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should show the exact commands you use for getting the numbers that you mention.

Comment: Check if you have device mounted on folders containing stuff. (Unmount all volumes then and see if in mounpoint there's stuff). PS: run these command as superuser or you won't see some of the files

Comment: Using `du -hx /` would _only_ do the root filesystem, ignoring other mount points.